# Is there an English equivalent to 「ふん」とする

Tags: translation, words, onomatopoeia

Ok so I think I've typed/spelled that right, but so I came across this phrase in a random children's book at a cat cafe I go to frequently. So I know what this means, it's like when you just act all sassy, lift your head dramatically to basically tell the other party to f-off as if you don't know them anymore.

But I could've sworn there is like some equivalent to this in English or at least something reasonably close. For the life of me I cannot really put my finger it, I feel like it's something along the lines of onomatopoeia in English as well or something similar to that. The two things my brain keeps coming to are like huff and puff but I feel like that's not even close.

Sorry for the vagueness but it's about all I can come up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Humph", "pish", etc., perhaps?

Comment: So I was at the cafe again and I managed to get some time to remember what it was. It was written as ふん　と　しらんぷり
Any ideas?